# Unable to install dict4ini in Pycharm dev environment

Tags: python, pycharm

I try to add the `dict4ini` library in Pycharm:

[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I can't find this library on the list, and script does not run

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably [PY-29611](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29611) bug result - installation failed but PyCharm reports success. Please update PyCharm to get the fix. Meanwhile, you can try to install the package in the terminal to receive the hidden installation error.